# How to obtain RadTreeView children's margin?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radtreeview

I'm using `telerik:RadTreeView` with the following code

```
<telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="ViewPlaybackTreeView" Uid="-1" IsTriStateMode="True" Style="{StaticResource SettingTreeViewStyle}" 
ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SettingRadTreeViewTimePickerItemStyle}">
    <telerik:RadTreeViewItem x:Name="ViewPlaybackTreeViewItem" Uid="-1" IsExpanded="False" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SettingRadTreeViewTimePickerItemStyle}"/>
</telerik:RadTreeView>

<Style x:Key="SettingTreeViewStyle"  TargetType="telerik:RadTreeView">
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Extended"/>
    <Setter Property="IsLineEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsOptionListType" Value="CheckList"/>
    <Setter Property="IsOptionElementsEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="IsRootLinesEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTriStateMode" Value="True"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="SettingRadTreeViewTimePickerItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}">
                <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid x:Name="HeaderRow" Background="Transparent" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Column="2" CornerRadius="2"/>
                        <Border x:Name="SelectionUnfocusedVisual" BorderBrush="#FFDBDBDB" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Column="2" CornerRadius="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF8F6F9" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="SelectionVisual" BorderBrush="#FFFFC92B" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Column="2" CornerRadius="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFCE79F" Offset="1"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFDD3A8"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="IndentContainer" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="IndentFirstVerticalLine" Stroke="#FFCCCCCC" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Grid x:Name="ListRootContainer" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="20">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalLine" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="1" Stroke="#FFCCCCCC" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalLine" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stroke="#FFCCCCCC" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1"/>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsTabStop="False"/>
                            <Grid x:Name="LoadingVisual" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="0" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <Path Data="M1,0A1,1,90,1,1,0,-1" Height="10" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" StrokeThickness="1" Width="10"/>
                                <Path Data="M0,-1.1L0.1,-1 0,-0.9" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="4" Margin="5,-1.5,0,0" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="4"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxElement" Grid.Column="2" IsTabStop="False" Visibility="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource UserTreeSettingCheckboxStyle}">
                        </CheckBox>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonElement" Grid.Column="2" IsTabStop="False" Margin="5,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                                <telerik:Office_BlackTheme/>
                            </telerik:StyleManager.Theme>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <Image x:Name="Image" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="16" MaxHeight="16" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Column="2" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="4">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Header" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="EditHeaderElement" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderEditTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="TimeStart" Grid.Column="6" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Format="Custom" FormatString="HH:mm"/>
                        <toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="TimeEnd" Grid.Column="6" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Format="Custom" FormatString="HH:mm"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsInEditMode" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Header" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="EditHeaderElement" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" TargetName="CheckBoxElement" Value="True"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" TargetName="CheckBoxElement" Value="True"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF52686E"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsLoadingOnDemand" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="LoadingVisualTransform">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" From="0" RepeatBehavior="Forever" To="359" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" Storyboard.TargetName="LoadingVisualAngleTransform"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="LoadingVisualTransform"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="LoadingVisual" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF1E7787"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the result when run this code as below picture
[image]

The problem is two first TimePickers is not "Left Alignment" with below ones.
I think I can set their left margin to correct it, but I don't know the exactly "left margin" value that I have to set.

Someone can show me how to solve my problem?

Many thanks!

T&T

Answer (score 1):

It's a fixed margin for each level, so you use a converter to set the margin to level * fixed margin. Play around a bit to get the right value.

But I would suggest not using the RadTreeView like this. Telerik has another component which solves this in a much nicer way. RadTreeListView (http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radtreelistview-overview.html). It works just like a regular treeview, but you can make columns next to your tree which automatically aligns your controls or whatever you put in them. If you set the margin you are depending on the graphical properties which may change with different styles.

```
public class MarginConverter : IValueConverter
{
    const int FIXED_MARGIN = 30;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value * FIXED_MARGIN;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value / FIXED_MARGIN;
    }  
}
```

```
<telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="ViewPlaybackTreeView" Uid="-1" IsTriStateMode="True" >
        <telerik:RadTreeViewItem x:Name="ViewPlaybackTreeViewItem" Uid="-1" IsExpanded="False" Margin="{Binding Level, Converter={StaticResource MarginConverter }}"/>
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

And then add a Level property to your class.

Comment: Thank you David, can you give me the example code for "converter to set the margin to level * fixed margin" as you mentioned. I don't know it.

Comment: See the example. But I really recommend trying the RadTreeListView.